# Making on click event work with AJAX & PHP loading php files into div?

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

Currently I have this code for loading a file into a div. At the moment when I click on one of the options it simply links to the page instead of loading the page into the div with AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.eventSelect').click(function(){
    var url = 'includes/events.php';
    $('.content').load(url); 
  });
});   

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.podSelect').click(function(){
    //Retrieve Content from the back-end PHP page, and pass the ID selected
    var url = 'includes/content.php';
    $('.content').load(url); 
  });
});
```

This is the code with the two options to click. So if I click pods, the content for the pods would then appear in the div class(content) and the same for events.

```
echo "<div id=\"viewSelect\">";
echo "<div class=\"eventSelect\">";
echo "<a href=\"/../includes/events.php\">";
echo "events";
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"podSelect\">";
echo "<a href=\"/../includes/events.php\">";
echo "pods";
echo "</a>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

I think my problem is to do with a href but I'm not sure.

If anyone can help that would be great, thanks.

Comment: I've tried removing href completely but then there is nothing to click, is there certain which I need to link the jquery with the href links?

Comment: Put `return false;` after `$('.content').load(url);`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to return false from your click handlers to prevent the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your JS to following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#viewSelect > a').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.content').load(url);
        return false; 
      });
    });
```

**What's happening above**
`$(document).ready();` <-- Makes sure code runs after document is loaded

`$('#viewSelect > a').click();` <-- Bind all `anchor` tags inside `viewSelect` id to `click` event

`$(this).attr('href');` <-- Fetch clckeked  `anchor href` attribute

`return false;`  <-- Prevents Default functionality (Here hyperlink redirect)

**Some suggestions**

- You don't need to replicate same functionality twice. This can be
  acheived by single function only.
- Also I don't see any reason why you have enclosed plain `HTML` in `php
  echo` statements. This is just an unnecessary overhead for server.
- Read [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/)  properly and don't initiate
  `$(document).ready()` each time you write a new function.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `<a>` tag

```
echo "<div id=\"viewSelect\">";
echo "<div class=\"eventSelect\">";
echo "events";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I've done this but then I cannot hover over events and click so that doesn't work.

Comment: have you try look at that page using chrome developer tools? or firebug? what does it show there? and try replace your link with "#"

Answer (score 0):

have you heard of jquery bro?...give jquery a try this will solve your problem.

```
function loadAjax(url,display)
{ $("."+display).html('Loading Content Please Wait...'); 
$.get(url,function(data){  $("."+display).html(data) }); }
```

now params are

```
 url=ajax feed to load (eg. includes/events.php)
    display = where to show your feed result. (eg. content)
```

use like this

```
<div class="content"></div> 
<a Onclick='loadAjax("includes/events.php","content")'>Click To Load Events</a>
<a Onclick='loadAjax("includes/contents.php","content")'>Click To Load Events</a>
```

Obviously you need the jquery library for this to work.